# RFID BLUETOOTH PHP

Tags: php, bluetooth

Estou tentando conectar um leitor RFID ao Windows via Bluetooth.

Consigo identificar qual a 'COM' ele está, porém quando tento chamar via PHP usando 'fopen' por exemplo, da erro "failed to open stream: Permission denied".

Tentei utilizar a função PHPSERIAL, mas também da erro: "Warning: Specified serial port is not valid in C:\xampp\htdocs\serial\PhpSerial.php on line 120".

Tentei executar via terminal o comando "MODE COM7:9600,n,8,1", e da a msg "O dispositivo COM7 não está disponível neste momento."

Em todos os casos, o leitor chega a bipar, porém gera o erro.

Alguém já trabalhou com algo do tipo?

Segue os códigos testados.

```
<?php
    include 'PhpSerial.php';
    $serial = new PhpSerial;
    $serial->deviceSet("COM7");
    $serial->confBaudRate(2400);
    $serial->confParity("none");
    $serial->confCharacterLength(8);
    $serial->confStopBits(1);
    $serial->confFlowControl("none");
    $serial->deviceOpen();
?>

<?php
    $port = fopen("COM7", "r+b");
    echo fgets($port);
    fclose($port);
?>
```

Comment: `fopen`é para abrir um arquivo, no teu caso, para leitura. Onde está o arquivo?

Comment: Vi algumas pessoas dando exemplo de abrir conexão com porta serial usando "FOPEN", fornecendo somente a "COM" como no exemplo acima, acabei testando o código. Não tenho experiencia com porta serial, bluetooth, então qualquer coisa é válida para se chegar ao resultado desejado rs

Comment: Não sei se php seria a linguagem  adequada para o que você quer, mas  já tentou executar o  xampp  no modo de administrador ?

Comment: Qual seria a linguagem adequada? Executei como ADM, porém continua a mesma coisa.

Comment: Eu acredito que python é melhor para mexer com isso....mas nunca mexi.

Comment: https://github.com/karulis/pybluez

Comment: Encontrei um software demo que disponibiliza o código fonte VS, porém não tenho a minima expediência com o mesmo. O mesmo consegue fazer a comunicação com o leitor e não gera nenhum erro. Encontrei outros softwares também, e em comum, todos usam a "RFIDReaderLibrary.dll".

Comment: Quando você liga seu dispositivo Bluetooth, ele ficará disponível para ser "enxergado" pelo seu computador. Neste momento você deve fazer o pareamento deste dispositivo (não esqueça de habilitar antes o Bluetooth de seu computador). Só então você poderá abrir uma conexão para o dispositivo, seja na linguagem que for. Feito o pareamento, então você deve verificar em qual porta `COM` o dispositivo está habilitado. Aí sim você indica em seu código a porta certa. Sugestão: antes de codificar, tente abrir a conexão com um programa tipo `PuTTy` ou outro parecido.

Comment: @wBB, todos os procedimentos que você citou eu já estava fazendo, único teste que não fiz foi com o PuTTy, mas entendo que se não funcionou com o CMD que é "básicão", provavelmente também não irá funcionar no PuTTy.

Comment: @WilliamAparecidoBrandino Usei o PuTTy para abrir a COM e funcionou.

Comment: Até consegui mandar os comandos para iniciar a leitura das tags, abortar, e funcionou de boas pelo PuTTy.

Comment: Isso significa que o problema não está nem no seu dispositivo, nem na porta COM do seu PC, nem na comunicação em si. De onde conclui-se que está na parte da programação. Não tenho como fazer um teste para você, mas outra sugestão agora seria você usar uma linguagem diferente para saber se funciona ou, caso queira insistir no PHP, tente outros métodos. Se for usar linguagem C, tem um monte de exemplos sobre comunicação serial prontos na NET e você poderia testar rapidamente.

Comment: Tem uns demos em C, C#, que funcionam a comunicação, efetuam a leitura, etc, o meu problema é q seria para utilizar em um sistema PHP já existente, então estou vendo as possibilidades.

Comment: Mesmo sendo um sistema PHP daria para utilizar o python, já que python  é nativo linux e o PHP poderia chama-lo via shell

Comment: Se seu equipamento gera logs em algum TXT no windows, seria legal considerar ler o Log ao invés de conectar no equipamento com o PHP.
Voce conseguindo gerar este log, poderia ate mesmo fazer algo assincrono com um servidor e ter o dado em tempo real em nuvem.

Answer (score 3):

Lidar com hardware muito específico a partir de linguagens de alto nível geralmente é um desafio, principalmente se for em aplicações Web. Algumas considerações sobre o seu problema e uma sugestão de solução:

O fato do leitor bipar significa que a leitura foi feita no próprio leitor, mas não significa que o valor lido foi enviado a um destino através de alguma interface. Se o leitor é wireless, ele pode nem mesmo estar pareado ao computador, mas acusar a leitura, se estiver energizado.

Se você já detectou que o leitor está pareado ao computador, bastaria acessar a porta correspondente e obedecer o protocolo de comunicação. Pelo que entendi, você já venceu essa etapa e descobriu que o leitor está mapeado na porta COM7.

Sua pergunta não deixa claro que tipo de aplicação você está construindo, se é um script PHP rodando em linha de comando ou se esse código será executado em uma página Web. Se o código for executado em uma página Web, lembre-se que ele irá procurar o leitor **na porta COM do servidor onde roda o script PHP**, não no cliente Windows, a não ser que o servidor Web seja executado no cliente Windows.

De qualquer maneira, a classe PhpSerial só funciona em modo read/write no Linux. No Windows ela não é capaz de ler o que vem da porta, apenas escrever na porta. Além disso, essa classe é experimental e cheia de bugs, então eu não confiaria nela para rodar uma aplicação real em produção.

Sugiro que você use outra linguagem para conectar-se à porta serial e receber o resultado da leitura. Coloque o código que faz a leitura em um serviço que vai rodar na máquina onde o leitor estiver pareado. Esse serviço pode ser feito usando alguma linguagem nativa do Windows (C#, VB etc.), C, C++, Java ou em cima do Node.js, por exemplo.

Quando o leitor bipar, o serviço recebe o resultado e armazena em um buffer, disponibilizando uma interface HTTP para consulta. O tamanho do buffer e a estrutura de dados (FIFO, LIFO etc.) vai depender do seu requisito de negócio, ou seja, com que frequência a aplicação precisa receber o valor lido. A sua aplicação então busca o valor via `HTTP GET` no localhost. Se for uma aplicação Web, basta fazer via *request* AJAX quando o cursor for posicionado no campo, lembrando de configurar no seu serviço o *Header* HTTP `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` com o servidor de origem da página, para que o `CORS (Cross-Origin Request Sharing)` funcione.

Uma vez lido pela interface HTTP, o valor é removido do *buffer*.

Não é uma solução trivial, mas já desenvolvi algo parecido que roda perfeitamente em centenas de clientes há alguns anos. O lado negativo dessa solução é ter que desenvolver e manter um serviço a mais, além de precisar monitorar esse serviço, para identificar se travou.

Comment: Meu sistema está hospedado na Web, em um servidor dedicado LINUX. A ideia seria que o sistema web (PHP) chamasse o leitor que está pareado "localmente", realize a leitura e retorne o conteúdo para a web. Óbvio q não é tão fácil assim, permissões, segurança, etc. Neodynamic tem algo parecido com o que preciso, porém voltado para impressão, o software WebClientPrint Processor com suporte ao PHP, onde vc instala no computador cliente, o script da web faz a chamada e envia a impressão.

Comment: Consegui pegar uns exemplos na web e consegui desenvolver um console onde identifica e lista os dispositivos bluetooth pareados, inicia a conexão com o leitor, inicia o recebimento de tags, finaliza e salva direto no banco de dados. Seria possível chamar esse .exe em um dado momento?

Comment: Desculpe, é um "Aplicativo do Windows", .NET 4.5. É q n tenho prática ou conhecimento em questão de console, aplicativos, etc. Exemplo de caso: o RH da empresa acessa o sistema web, cadastra um novo funcionário e atrela o crachá RFID. Para atrelar, o ideal seria chamar a conexão com o leitor nesse momento, realizar a leitura da tag, e o retorno voltaria para o navegador para prosseguir com o cadastro. Com o q vc disse de HTTP/AJAX, o cenário seria possível? Teria alguns termos para pesquisar e dar uma lida para ter melhor entendimento ou algum exemplo? Estou meio perdido rs.

Answer (score 0):

Verifique as permissões do servidor de página (na máquina onde você roda o PHP), pois esse erro de permissão que você está vendo deve estar vindo de daí...

Outras coisas:

1) não sei em que pé está atualmente, mas me parece que o PHP só aceita até a porta `COM5`. Mais que isso pode dar erro;

2) Troque o seu segundo parâmetro do `fopen` de `"r+b"` para `w+` para testar. Ficará `fopen("COMx", "w+");` onde **COMx** tem que ser igual ou menor a **COM5**.

Comment: 2) Testei todas as possibilidades do fopen.

Comment: veja se isso ajuda: https://www.phpclasses.org/package/3679-PHP-Communicate-with-a-serial-port.html

Comment: lembrando que o dispositivo com o qual você vai estabelecer a comunicação tem que estar conectado ao mesmo PC/servidor onde o PHP está instalado.